# Prove Confidence of Rule

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-mining, dataset, subset

Using Association.

I want to prove the confidence of the rule $B'->(A\B')$ can't be more than the confidence of $B->(A\B)$

Given:

- frequent itemset $A$ and subsets $B$ of $A$.
- $B'$ is a subset of $B$.

"\" is the [Set Difference Operator](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html) Sometimes written like this: $(X-Y)$

[image: Dataset]

I found the exact question on this book: Data Mining: *Concepts and Tenchniques by Jiawei Han* online, under Mining Frequent Patterns, Association, and Correlations chapter
[6.3 (c) on this book.](http://books.google.com/books?id=pQws07tdpjoC&pg=PA273&lpg=PA273&dq=Given%20frequent%20itemset%20A%20and%20subsets%20B%20of%20A,%20prove%20that%20the%20confidence%20of%20the%20rule&source=bl&ots=txLvYSqF1-&sig=Wmx08DOhYnSgaBXBqZT17rFxPkM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0ZuQUp6hI8yHkQfZnICoBg&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false)
Doesn't say anything on how to solve it though.

Comment: This may be drawing on definitions in some literature. It does not seem related at all to the mainstream statistical sense in which "confidence" implies "confidence interval". Giving some sources and/or more explanation would help greatly. Otherwise $(X|Y)$ suggests only $X$ given $Y$; are you reaching towards conditional probability? In any case, how does your last sentence relate to the rest of the question?

Comment: I got it from an example, which now makes me think it is wrong. So I am removing that line.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not make the overall question clear. Remove _my_ last sentence above, but the rest stands.

Comment: Sorry, not to me. You are giving the impression that you are giving your own definition to a word that already has an established technical meaning in statistical science.  Someone else may be able to help.

Comment: Yeah I am probably giving my own definition because I am lost. Sorry for confusion you so much. I found the exact same question on this online book. I posted the link above. They use $B$ as $s$ and use $-$ to represent the set difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [association rule learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning), the confidence of a rule is defined as follows:
$$conf(X\Rightarrow Y) = \frac{support(X\cup Y)}{support(X)}$$

The confidence is the amount of times a rule has been encountered in the data, conditional on the amount of times its left hand side was encountered. $100\%$ confidence implies that any record containing $X$ also contains $Y$. Confidence is one of the key criteria used to filter rules.

Unless I am misinterpreting parts of your question, it looks flawed to me, since the following rule is a paradox: $X\Rightarrow Y\setminus X$. Here you are asking for records which contain $X$ (left hand side) which also do *not* contain $X$ (right hand side). Long story short: the confidence of any such rule is exactly $0$, because an itemset cannot be present and absent at the same time.

Comment: I think it is some trick question/sick joke. I keep finding the question online, nobody knows how to solve it.